# Disable validation unique constraint in edit mode symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have unique validation for slug field and it works well in create mode. but I have no idea how to apply some conditional statement in edit mode.

1. if slug value has change from older value ( enable unique validation ).
2. if slug has not change ( disable unique validation ).

here is my validation:

```
Mockizart\StoreBundle\Entity\MockstoreCategory:
constraints:
  - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: slug
properties:
name:
  - NotBlank: ~
  - Length:
      min: 8
      max: 50
slug:
  - Length:
      min: 8
      max: 80
description:
  - NotBlank: ~
  - Length:
      min: 10
      max: 255
file:
  - Length:
      max: 150
  - File :
      maxSize: 6000000
```

I'm using `doctrine2` and `symfony2`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it works, here is my code:

**validation.yml:** (add group validation to validation.yml)

```
  constraints:
  - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
      fields: [slug]
      groups: [New]
```

**CategoryType.php:** (set static method that returning array groups name)

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Mockizart\StoreBundle\Entity\MockstoreCategory',
        'validation_groups' => array(
            'Mockizart\StoreBundle\Entity\MockstoreCategory',
            'isSlugHasChange',
        ),
    ));

}
```

**Mockizart\StoreBundle\Entity\MockstoreCategory:** (Default = no unique validation)

```
static $oldSlug;

public static function isSlugHasChange(FormInterface $form)
{
    if (self::$oldSlug) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        if (self::$oldSlug == $data->slug) {
            return array('Default');
        }
    }
    return array('Default','New');
}
```

**createAction:** (set old slug static property)

```
        if ($id) {
        $category = $this->getRepo('MockstoreCategory')->find($id);
        if (!$category) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No category found for id ' . $id
            );
        }
        $category::$oldSlug = $category->getSlug();
    }
```

Links:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data

Hope this help someone who is facing same problem. if you know better than this, please let me know.. Thanks!